# sfm/slam implementing with webcam

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, slam, structure-from-motion

I want to implement Structur from Motion (SfM) / Simultaneous Localization and mapping algorithms using my webcam. I am very new on this topic so I need advices from experts in the internet. I could now able to build OpenCV [opencv sfm tutorial](http://www.siddharth-agrawal.com/build-opencv-sfm-on-windows/) for this purpose and I looked OpenSFM but it seems like just a GUI. What other open libraries/programs that I can use for this task? any suggestions/advices/tutorials are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! That being said, I don't think this is a good question as it sounds like "I want to do math. Any advice?". Judging from your question, I think it is better for you to familiarize yourself with the literature before jumping into writing code. Read about basic techniques related to feature-based SLAM (bundle adjustment, pnp), and once you are done with that take a look at what dense or semi-dense slam has to offer. Look at minimal parametrization and non-linear minimization, pose graph formalisms... Once you understand the underlying math, you can decide what to do.

Comment: But if you just want to test something out of the box, there are many libraries, such as ORBSALM, OKVIS (visual-inertial), DSO, and so on... Also, PTAM and snavely's bundler are classics. Finally, I'm absolutely not sure that a webcam is a good choice (it probably has a rolling shutter among other problems, plus are you going to wave your laptop around?)